# How many students must write a test to ensure that at least $32$ have the same final score?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A math contest is made up of $64$ multiple choice questions each worth either $0$ (if wrong or no answer) or $1$ (if right). Then the number of students who must write the test to be sure that at least $32$ have the same final score is

A. $2016$

B. $52C39$

C. $39^{52}$

D. None of the above

My Approach:

There are $64$ questions so max marks can be $64$ and minimum marks can be $0$.  So there are $65$ possible marks from $0$ to $64$.  Now how to determine the number of students who get exactly the same marks?  Here is where I am stuck.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

Let's apply the pigeonhole principle. If we will have 31 * 65 + 1 = 2016 students, then there is mark (hole) has no less than 32 students (pigeons).

[The pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)

Suppose we have $n$ holes and $k$ pigeons. Then if we put pigeons in the holes (each hole can contain arbitrary number of pigeons and all pigeons must be used), then there is a hole with at least $k + 1$ pigeons. Proof: suppose there is no hole with at least $k + 1$ pigeons, so each hole contains less than $k + 1$ pigeon, or $\leq k$ pigeons. Therefore the sum of all the pigeons is $\leq nk$, and we get the contradiction.

The easier and more common version: if we have $n$ holes and $n+1$ pigeon, there is a hole with at least 2 pigeons.

Comment: Thank you sooobus..I am not aware of the pigeonhole principle.Can you explain it in brief here?Thanks a lot again.....:)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we start giving scores to students and we stop when one score reaches 32 times.

The worst that could happen initially is that every score from 0 to 64 would occur 31 times. This takes $65 \cdot 31= 2015$ students. But if we now add one and then one score *must* occur 32 times. With 2015 students this need not happen, but with 2016 it cannot be avoided.